# A fantasy book about a princess who lives with "ash people"

Tags: story-identification

Ok I need some help here I have been stumped, its a fantasy book over 10 years old, about a princess, locked in a castle, city is surrounded by a wall, a prince is trying to kill her, and she escaped the castle to live among the "ash people" who are concidered the lowest of society.??? Anyone????

Comment: Any more details you can add to this?

Comment: You might want to work your way through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). For example, what can you tell us about the Princess and the Prince? Why was he trying to kill her? How did she escape? In what way was the story a fantasy? How did it end?